# A simple email client/contact form is returning a "5.5.4 Invalid Domain Error" and I have exhausted all my resources attempting to solve it

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I've posted this question twice in the last two days and I have really run dry of solutions. I'm creating a very simple comment box that when filled out sends the comment in an email to my company's safety department. I have been receiving this 5.5.4 Invalid Domain Error for the last couple days.

It's SMTP and TLS. The port and server name is correct. The server allows for anonymous emails, and does not validate. I'm using the Swiftmailer library so I shouldn't need to script a ELHO/HELO. The only property of the email that's not defined/hard coded is the body of the message. This is the code for my controller (index.php).

```
// Initialize Swiftmailer Library
require_once("./swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php"); 

// Class that contains the information of the email that will be sent (from, to, etc.)
require_once("./classes/EmailParts.php");

// The class that "breaks" the data sent with the HTML form to a more "usable" format.
require_once("./classes/ContactForm.php");

// =====================
// Main Configuration
// =====================

define("EMAIL_SUBJECT", "Safety Concerns");     
define("EMAIL_TO", "safetydepartment@company.com"); 
define("EMAIL_FROM", "safetydepartment@company.com");   

// SMTP Configuration
define("SMTP_SERVER", 'exchange.company.local');                
define("SMTP_PORT", 25);                                

function main($contactForm) {

    // Checks if something was sent to the contact form, if not, do nothing
    if (!$contactForm->isDataSent()) {
        return;
    }

    // Validates the contact form and checks for errors
    $contactForm->validate();

    $errors = array();

    // If the contact form is not valid:
    if (!$contactForm->isValid()) {
        // gets the error in the array $errors
        $errors = $contactForm->getErrors();

    } else {
        // If the contact form is valid:
        try {               
            // send the email created with the contact form
            $result = sendEmail($contactForm);              

            // after the email is sent, redirect and "die".
            // We redirect to prevent refreshing the page which would resend the form
            header("Location: ./success.php");
            die();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // an error occured while sending the email. 
            // Log the error and add an error message to display to the user.
            error_log('An error happened while sending email contact form: ' . $e->getMessage());
            $errors['oops'] = 'Ooops! an error occured while sending your email! Please try again later!';
        }

    }

    return $errors;
}

// Sends the email based on the information contained in the contact form
function sendEmail($contactForm) {
    // Email part will create the email information needed to send an email based on 
    // what was inserted inside the contact form
    $emailParts = new EmailParts($contactForm);

    // This is the part where we initialize Swiftmailer with 
    // all the info initialized by the EmailParts class
    $emailMessage = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject($emailParts->getSubject())
    ->setFrom($emailParts->getFrom())
    ->setTo($emailParts->getTo())
    ->setBody($emailParts->getBodyMessage());

    // Another Swiftmailer configuration..
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT, 'tls');
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $result = $mailer->send($emailMessage);
    return $result;
}

// Initialize the ContactForm with the information of the form and the possible uploaded file.
$contactForm = new ContactForm($_POST, $_FILES);

// Call the "main" method. It will return a list of errors. 
$errors = main($contactForm);

// Call the "contactForm" view to display the HTML contact form.
require_once("./views/contactForm.php");
```

I've posted the entirety of my code at [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vm9yushy2gxa07c/AAAasrEbv-Oz6r8vUAy0xUr5a?dl=0/%22Dropbox%22). There's not much, but I think the problem must lie in the Index.

Comment: Can you resolve exchange.company.local?

Comment: Yes, I can resolve it through PHP. I've tried running the code with the IP instead of the FQDN and it makes no difference.

Comment: can you send mails from that server to the given recipient/from the given sender, with smtptest (or telnet or whatever)?

Comment: Yes. I've sent an email over telnet to the server.

Comment: ok, so the only thing left obscure is the content of those emailparts. What does var_dump give you after creating emailMessage?

Comment: I'll check this when I'm at work tomorrow and respond. I should have done that already but I just started learning PHP on Friday so trying to figure out how to debug has been rough. I think I'll need to try and get some reputation on here so I can place a bounty.